# Is it possible for redshift to be caused by light being somehow slowed down during travel?

Tags: expansion, redshift

In other words, is the assumption, that redshift is caused by universe expansion, definitive? Or are other theories still being considered? Could it be, that light is being slowed down by dark energy, dark matter, massive objects, etc., as it travels through space?

Comment: @Chappo, answers to the older, very similar question (https://astronomy.stackexchange.com/questions/1973/is-there-another-explanation-apart-from-the-doppler-effect-for-the-redshift-ob) fit mine quite well. Thanks.

Comment: That's great, I'm glad our site has been able to provide the answers you needed :-)